# Django database connection error: "sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file"

Tags: python, django

So I just created a new project and app for the blog. When I try and syncdb it says:
"sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file"

I saw the noob FAQ and it says the possible errors are having an incorrect path or not giving apache permission to write to the folder.

Here is a dpaste with my settings.py and some terminal outputs to give you an idea of what's up.

http://dpaste.org/eQUm/

If the solution is to give apache permission to write, how would i do it? I am running the server on a personal computer on ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670289/sqlite3-operationalerror-unable-to-open-database-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the path to the database file, look at your database settings:

```
'NAME': '/home/vmplanet/code/blog', # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
```

...which is presumably the project directory. Try `/home/vmplanet/code/blog/blog.db`.

Comment: Also note that django won't accept `'~/code/blog/blog.db'`, you need to pass the full path. I was having this problem and saw the exact same error message.