# Changing file permissions for Apache - Django

Tags: python, django, apache

I'm trying to modify file permissions in Linux so that Apache and Django have permission to read and write to the database. The path of my database file is

```
/var/www/tbg/database/database.sqlite3
```

I use these commands

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/tbg
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/tbg/database/database.sqlite3
```

Yet I get the same error (same error as is described here: [sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670289/sqlite3-operationalerror-unable-to-open-database-file)).

To make sure the permissions are still not there, I can't paste content or create new folders. I can in the the subfolders of `/tbg/`, though, but not in `/tbg/` itself.

Comment: run `ls -l` on the directory. Lets see the file permissions

Comment: I deleted my former comment, I accidentally took a screenshot of the /tbg/ file itself, which already has permissions. This is the permissions for directories inside /www/, including /tbg/: http://i.imgur.com/4JNwqzZ.png

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I had neglected to change the file permissions of the directories inside /tbg/! With `ls -l` I was able to figure this out and then I typed

```
chmod www-data:www-data foldername
```

to enable apache to read and write to the directories. This must be done for every directory under your project's name (in my case /tbg/) -- and in every subdirectory under every subdirectory!

Comment: run `chmod www-data:www-data -R foldername` to change for every subdirectory