# Django: unable to open database file (is this a pathname issue?)

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite

For the last few days, I've been trying to sort out this error. When I run my script, I'm getting a Django "OperationalError: unable to open database file" error.
From what I've found on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636970/sqlite3-operationalerror-unable-to-open-database-file) and [this similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670289/sqlite3-operationalerror-unable-to-open-database-file?rq=1) (along with many a Google search), the **most common** issue is with someone using a relative path rather than an absolute path, or having some sort of typo in one of the strings.

Here is the code *relevant to my paths*:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DATA_FILE = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data', 'mydbtester.db')

...

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': DATA_FILE,
    }
}
```

To my understanding, the code above the `...` should be getting the absolute path to the directory **two directories up from the current file**, then joining it with the `data` directory and the database name and file extension.  I have checked that this file exists, and it does indeed exist in the stated location; the name matches exactly. I am also absolutely sure that the current user has permissions for this file.

I am also unable to `migrate` the database, with the exact same error.

Does anyone know why this is causing the OperationalError, or perhaps if there is something else going on?

Note: I am also having this issue when running in a Docker container.

Much appreciated.

EDIT:

After adding a `print(DATA_FILE)` statement under the DATA_FILE declaration, it seems that the `BASE_DIR` is only moving one directory up when it needs to move up by two. To see if this was the issue, I've moved the `data` directory down one directory, and it started working. *However*, this is not the way my project should be structured. Any help to get the `BASE_DIR` to reference one more directory up?

Comment: Can you do `print DATA_FILE` there to see if it is what you expect?

Comment: @DanielRoseman if I add a `print(DATA_FILE)` line there, it prints the path to `DATA_FILE` twice, then decides to break again.

Comment: But is the path correct?

Comment: OH MY.
No, actually. I didn't even notice that.
It appears that it's only moving one directory up instead of two in the `BASE_DIR` line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `dirname` literally gets the dir name that the file is in, not its parent.

You probably should do:

```
DATA_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'data', 'mydbtester.db'))
```

Comment: Perfect, this worked after moving the file back to where it was before. Thanks!