# OperationalError at / unable to open database file Appears Sporadically

Tags: python, django, apache, sqlite, permissions

I am getting the following error when I try to run a Django site in production:

> OperationalError at / unable to open database file

The strangest part is that it worked for a few page reloads and even clicks on different navigation links. Then, it worked every other time or so. At the end, it stopped working all together. This behavior is very puzzling.

Here is the relevant piece from settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

I have done `chmod 777 db.sqlite` as well as `chmod o+w .` within the directory where `db.sqlite3` is located. It did not help.

How could I fix this? I am using a basic EC2 instance with Linux and Apache 2.4

**Edit:**

I have just duplicated the entire directory of the project using `cp project project1` and then did `mv project1 project`. This made the site work for a few clicks, but then the error started creeping in again. Could this be a server issue?

Comment: do you have any other DB settings in your settings.py?

Comment: No I do not. No other settings related to DB.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: if you use the full path for the name, make sure the server can also write to the parent directory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670289/sqlite3-operationalerror-unable-to-open-database-file

Comment: "I have done chmod 777 db.sqlite as well as chmod o+w . within the directory where db.sqlite3 is located. It did not help." Do you have another suggestion on how to make the parent writeable?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by running the following two commands from within the directory where the DB file was stored:

`sudo chown apache:www db.sqlite3`

`sudo chown apache:www .`

This did it for me for AWS EC2 with Amazon Linux (CentOS)

Answer (score -1):

You set the name of your DB to the full path. Don't do this. Just say `'NAME': 'db.sqlite3'`

Comment: I set it like that because it gives server error otherwise.

Comment: If I set it like you suggest, I get `unable to open database file` if I set it with full path, I get `attempt to write a readonly database`

Comment: try do `chmod 777` for the directory containing your db.sqlite3

Comment: It is my understanding that that would highly unsafe if the DB is in root of the project?

Comment: I was able to fix it. See my answer. Thank you for your help!