# Unable to open database when updating values

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, plotly-dash

I show a datatable in Dash, where content is retrieved from an SQLite database using SQLAlchemy. I have checkmark boxes on the datatable and a button that updates that row (for example a column called `status`, where I change a value from "RESOURCE" to "FINISHED"). However, the callback function to update is unable to open the database:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file [SQL: UPDATE users SET status = ? where eventid = ?] [Parameters: ('FINISHED', 8)]
```

Layout elements :

```py
html.Button('Set Event Complete', id="complete-event"),
html.Div(id='output-message'),
html.Div(dash_table.DataTable(  # Datatable that includes the data from the data gathering method
    id='datatable-paging-filtering',    
    columns=[
        {"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],    
    data=df.to_dict("records"),    
    page_size=PAGE_SIZE,    
    page_current=0,
    filter_action='native',
    sort_action='native',
    sort_mode='multi',
    column_selectable="single",
    row_deletable=True,
    row_selectable="multi",
    selected_columns=[],
    selected_rows=[]
))
```

Callback function :

```py
@app.callback(
    Output('output-message', 'children'),
    [Input('complete-event', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('datatable-paging-filtering', 'data'),
     State('datatable-paging-filtering', 'selected_rows')]
)
def update_database(n_clicks, rows, selected_rows):
    if n_clicks is None:
        return json.dumps('')
    else:
        for i in selected_rows:
            rows[i]['status'] = 'FINISHED'
                
            conn = engine.connect()
            stmt = text("UPDATE users SET status = :status WHERE eventid = :eventid")
            conn.execute(stmt, {"status": 'FINISHED', "eventid": rows[i]['eventid']})
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
        return json.dumps('Event status updated successfully!')
```

Database configuration :

```py
server = Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server)
PAGE_SIZE = 15    

server.config.update(
    SECRET_KEY=os.urandom(12),
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///C:\\Users\\XXXXXXX\\OneDrive - XXX XXXX XXX\\Documents\\Dashtesting\\db2.sqlite',
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS=False
)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///C:\\Users\\XXXXXXX\\OneDrive - XXX XXX XXX\\Documents\\Dashtesting\\db2.sqlite', echo=True)
```

The goal is to actually update the database. I am able to retrieve data from the database, the problem occurs when I try to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to move the database somewhere else, to see if the path is causing problems. The issues might be that the folder-name contain spaces, or that flask/python don't have write-access to the parent folder. [See if these tips help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7670618/6697295).

Comment: You are exactly correc.t. The file didnt have writing perms for that directory, so i moved the db and it worked